# WSO2 Products with MySQL Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-bam

I have configured AM and BAM on the same machine.

I am using a MySQL database for both.

All worked correctly, but when I rebooted the system, I saw this error:

```
[2014-05-08 17:33:55,677] ERROR - DefaultRealmService Cannot initialize the realm.
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:168)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:411)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:223)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:114)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:356)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2502)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2321)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:344)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:158)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:258)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:306)
        ... 41 more
```

Comment: Do you start the mysql server when you reboot or does it startup automatically when windows starts?. and does this go away after a while?

Comment: BAM and AM are in same machine. Mysql is in other machine. All machines are Linux. I only reboot the BAM+AM machine.

Comment: From the error what it seems like is that the machine with BAM cannot properly connect to the mysql server. does this error go away after a while.and is the internet connection properly running by the time you restart BAM?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason can be since you have mapped, bind-address to an IP in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

The default is 0.0.0.0 which is all interfaces. This setting does not restrict which IPs can access the server, unless you specified 127.0.0.1 for localhost only or some other IP.

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

Once this is done, restart mysql server.

sudo service mysql restart